# Mono: Problems with Parallel.For

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, mono, task-parallel-library, parallel-extensions

I'm using `Task.Parallel` class from the **Microsoft Reactive Extensions** (the **.NET 3.5 library**, not the ones from .NET 4, since my app is running on 3.5). Everything works fine on .NET, but when I run it in Mono (2.10.5, on Linux), it throws an exception when calling the `Parallel.For()` method:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskSchedulerException: TaskSchedulerException_ctor_DefaultMessage 
 ---> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: SwitchToThread
 at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Threading.Platform:SwitchToThread ()
 at System.Threading.Platform.Yield () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 at System.Threading.ManualResetEventSlim.Wait (Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 at System.Threading.ManualResetEventSlim.Wait () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InternalRunSynchronously (System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler scheduler) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InternalRunSynchronously (System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler scheduler) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunSynchronously (System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler scheduler) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[Object] (Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions parallelOptions, System.Action`1 body, System.Action`2 bodyWithState, System.Func`4 bodyWithLocal, System.Func`1 localInit, System.Action`1 localFinally) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I couldn't find any resources on the Web covering this exception, so I'm kind of stuck. Any suggestions? Does Task Parallel library for 3.5 run at all on Mono?

Comment: Which version of the Reactive extensions library are you using? (If it is any consolation, and it is probably not relevant, but I installed the PFX library from here: http://nuget.org/packages/TaskParallelLibrary with the command Install-Package TaskParallelLibrary in VS on windows (so version 1.0.2856.0), built a simple Parallel.For console application then copied the exe and the DLL to a Mac running mono 2.10.9 and it ran fine).

Comment: @kmp: I'm using the same version, also through NuGet. It works without problems on my Linux Mint virtual machine, but breaks down on a netbook Linux Mint. Also breaks down on a user's Mac (also mono 2.10.9). I'll do some more testing using more and more complex Parallel.For loops and see how that goes. Thanks!

Comment: Having same problem with Unity3d in 2015 (not that suprising, since Unity just on principle won't be abreast of the times). Is there any solution?